# limiting the touchable area in a UIButton in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have three custom buttons with non-rectangular images close to each other in my view. Then I have a problem with touchable area's of each button overlap with other buttons. So how can I limit the touchable area of each buttons to get the corresponding actions?

Comment: you cannot limit the touch area of a `UIButton`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overwrite `-pointInside:withEvent:`, that internally will be used for hit testing.

A nice project using this technique is [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton), where transparent pixel will not trigger a hit.

Answer (score 3):

Use two components.  A `UIImageView` with a smaller `UIButton` on top.

Answer (score 3):

You should create custom Type Buttons and add required images on each using this code:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setFrame:frame];
```

Creating buttons with images this way will not result in overlapping images issues !!